# 1.9.3. At checkout, when client clicks on 'Place Order', (Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.) and it reloads the page

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, dhl

magento 1.9.3 using DHL Getting this Error

> Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.

```
checkout/onepage/
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error in ajax request. To check in which Ajax request error is there, you need to open console and in "Network" tab you can check error ajax request. Try to solve error which show in ajax response.

Comment: Ajax request is ok Any other Problem . i am using backend in Test Site Id Account Number  or password